# Zipping exe file benefits

Tags: zip, exe

I saw many times single exe file in zip folder and I was just wondering what sense it makes? Does it have some benefits? What is the purpose of doing that?

Is it meant to unzip it and then install. Or launch it from zipped folder?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically to protect your system, because of errors which happen during network transfer.

Because EXEs get corrupted in a non-detectable or non-fatal (as in, UAC prompt shows error but allows you to continue) manner. ZIPs, if corrupted, simply won't work at all.